# How to add eclipse project's class patth to ant script?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classpath

What is the easiest way to add project's classpath to custom ant script inside this project? Actually I need to be able to run java tasks with current project's classpath. Project can contain manual classpath entries, maven entries and so on - whatever eclipse allows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the answer is follows:

1) First we need to export current project into `build.xml` with `File->Export->Ant Buildfiles`.

This file can be used to compile project with `Ant` but what we need is the fact that this file will be synchronized with the project by `Eclipse`. Inside this file it will contain explicit definition of classpath, but these hardcodings will be under eclipse control.

2) Then import or include this in-sync XML file into custom one.

3) Inside custom file use `<classpath refid="MYPROJECTNAME.classpath"/>`